# Why does my regex works very slow when it contains '\r'

Tags: c#, html, regex

I'm just trying to replace header tag inside some html with another string.
My html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title>aboutus</title> 

    <header id="headerfasdfasdfasdf">
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer pulvinar commodo lorem, sit amet malesuada.</p>
    </header>

<!-- #include virtual="/html/US/global_header.html" --><script type="text/javascript">

   var header = document.getElementsByTagName("header");

    var len = header.length

    if(len > 1)

    {

    header[0].style.display = "none";

    }
</script>

    <!--ls:begin[component-1400226725207]-->

    <!-- OTHER PART IS CUT FOR BREVITY -->

</html>
```

I tried to parse it with regex `<header(.|\n|\r)*<\/header>`, but it works really slow until I remove `|\r` part from it.

Also I have noticed that original regex works fine with html that doesn't contain comments like `<!--ls:begin[component-1400226725207]-->`.

Note that I'm using .NET regex engine with C# and my replace code looks like this:

```
var regex = @"<header(.|\n|\r)*<\/header>";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, regex, to, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Please help me understand why do I have this issue.

Comment: Why? Browsers do not care about CRLF and you should not use RegEx to parse html. Why not just grab it from a renderer?

Comment: relevent: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2424975

Comment: @mplungjan, I know that I shouldn't but I don't have any choice for this part I only have result html and some part for insertion. I am more insterested why this regex works slow on this part.

Comment: That regex does *not* look safe (is greedyness wanted?), but regarding the speed remember that `.` with `RegexOptions.Singleline` will match any character including newlines.

Comment: @Robin Thanks for advise with singleline. Why doesn't it look safe and why '\r' could slow it down?

Answer (score 1):

if your input is pretty well sanitized (ie if you feel you [can use regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#answer-1733489)), this would probably improve your speed significantly:

```
var regex = @"<header.*?</header>";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, regex, to, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

- Avoid using `.|\n|\r` altogether, there's a flag for what you want to do.
- Make your quantifier lazy `*?` as the header tag probably doesn't take 2 third of your HTML

When backtracking from the end of the file to `</header>`, the greedyness of `(.|\n|\r)*` made the regex engine check every element of the alternation before trying `</header>`. Any element you add to alternation makes for potentially a lot of more work.

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I would use a simpler expression and tell it that . (dot) matches newlines too :-

```
(?s)(?U)<header.*\/header>
```

(?s) means match newlines as well as other characters with . (dot)
(?U) means match as few characters as possible

Comment: Whan I'm trying your regex in Regex.Replace - it says System.ArgumentException : parsing "(?s)(?U)<header.*\/header>" - Unrecognized grouping construct.

Comment: That's PHP regex syntax, not C#/POSIX